# Error message that resource could not be found on redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've deployed my ASP.NET web application to the local IIS on my computer which is running Windows 7 Pro.  When I try to open the web site the default page comes up fine but when I click on a button that does some processing and then redirects to another page I get the error:

> **Server Error in '/Book' Application.**
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> *Requested URL: /BookApp/Book.aspx*

The way I redirect to other pages is using Response.Redirect("~/Book.aspx", false);.  I've also tried other formats eg: /Book.aspx or Book.aspx but nothing seems to work so I'm at a complete loss how to fix this problem.

These files are located in the root folder of the website.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It means it can't find the file "/BookApp/Book.aspx". Where is the real location of that file? Have you look in the folder to see if it's actually there?

Comment: One thing I should add is that if I run the application from within Visual Studio, everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, the file is in the folder, I actually published the website to IIS using the Visual Studio publish feature

Comment: What should be the right url of that file? Can you access it directly?

Comment: What is the Url of the default page that works? localhost/bookapp or just localhost? What is the Url in the browser when you get this error?  localhost/bookapp/book.aspx or localhost/book.aspx?

Comment: I made a change to the re-directs in my code and removed slashes etc and simply had the page name and this seems to have done the trick.  I thought I had used the name only before but obviously was mistaken.  I must admit, I'm rather confused by when to use / or ../ or ~/ etc cause it seems like sometimes one way works then next time it doesn't.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility(v=vs.110).aspx: 'An absolute virtual path starts with the literal slash mark (/). A relative virtual path is relative to the application root directory, if it is just a tilde (~) or starts with the tilde and a double backslash (~\\) or the tilde and a slash mark (~/). Making a virtual path relative makes the path independent of the application.'